# addEventListener not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm converting a tutorial game into a stronger app pattern and ran into an issue refactoring my event listeners.

In the original code, I had the listeners set and callbacks defined in main function:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    GAME.init();
    function main() {
        GAME.stopMain = window.requestAnimationFrame(main);

        GAME.draw();

        GAME.update();
    } 

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            GAME.inputs.rightPressed = true;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            GAME.inputs.leftPressed = true;
        }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            GAME.inputs.rightPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            GAME.inputs.leftPressed = false;
        }
    }

    main();
})();
```

When I swapped my listeners and callbacks out for a call to `GAME.inputs.init();` and created this method of `GAME.inputs`:

```
GAME.inputs: {
    keyDownHandler: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            this.rightPressed = true;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            this.leftPressed = true;
        }
    },

    keyUpHandler: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            this.rightPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            this.leftPressed = false;
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler, false);
    }
};
```

The event listeners stopped registering. I had this issue once before and just reverted to the old way but I'd like to understand WHY this doesn't work.

Comment: I can think of several possible reasons, but you haven't provided a [MCVE] so I can't tell which of them is right. (In your test case, you never call `init` and your event handler functions don't *do* anything).

Comment: Have you checked that the handlers being called? That `init` has been called?

Comment: [Seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/gnvedxo3/)?

Comment: init WAS being called. the handlers initially had explicit references to properties of the GAME.inputs object. When I moved all of the input related code to this object I replaced the `GAME.input`'s with `this`'s.

I was trying to keep it light by omitting seemingly unimportant code. That's my bad. Thanks for such quick help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call bind so the scope of this is not the document.

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler.bind(this), false);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler.bind(this), false);
```

and depending on how it is initialized, it might actually be

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.inputs.keyDownHandler.bind(this), false);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", this.inputs.keyUpHandler.bind(this), false);
```

Comment: I don't think that can be the case. In the original code (which the OP said *worked*), `this` wasn't overridden, so both versions of the code should have `this` equal to `document` when the event handler is triggered (because event handlers are called in the context of the object to which they are bound).

Comment: In the original code, I wasn't using `this` for anything. I'll try a few of the bind options and see what works.

Comment: So passing a `this` reference as an argument from a method DOESN'T maintain a reference to the parent object? Thought I'd be fine until I got into the body of an internal function.

Ahhh.. I didn't type it but the new iterations of the keyHandlers have `this` references.